# How to make an undervoltage trip switch?

Tags: power-supply, switches, low-power, esp32, power-management

I want to make a switch which permanently cuts a power supply to a microcontroller when the supply voltage drops below a certain level.

I am powering an ESP32 development board from two 3.7V 18650 batteries. The board has a built-in AMS1117-3.3V regulator which regulates the voltage to the MCU at 3.3V. The microcontroller basically lives in deepsleep mode and just wakes up to send a byte of information to a server (hosted by an ESP8266 board) every hour. The problem that I am having is that there is no kill switch to turn off the microcontroller when the voltage gets too low. So the microcontroller just boots and fails continuously.

I know that you can turn off the MCU by pulling the ENABLE line low, but I need a switch to pull it low and remain in that state after being "tripped".

I hope it makes sense and I am open to any design ideas or alternatives that could work.

Comment: How permanent is permanently?

Comment: A microprocessor supervisor with a power-on-reset function is specifically designed for this and will cost you less than $1.

Comment: Like this:    https://forum.digikey.com/t/simple-undervoltage-and-overcurrent-protection-for-lithium-ion-and-lithium-polymer-batteries/13123

Comment: What releases the "lock" so the uC can star again?

Comment: @Hearth I want the trip switch to keep the ESP32 module off until the batteries are recharged (i.e. the voltage is above the limit at which it trips).

Comment: @vir I did a quick search on the web, there's lots of them - thanks. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: We can't give specific product recommendations on this site but just look for something with the correct voltage limits for your micro.

Comment: @vir I have a look into the uP supervisors and they are exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!